# Проблема загрузки текстур ASSIMP Qt6

Tags: qt, opengl, assimp

Проблема в неверном наложении текстур, в течении 2 дней так и ненашёл решения проблемы.

*Все действия вроде последовательные.
Вопрос, где при работе с библиотекой assimp, я возможно выполняю не верное подгрузку либо бинд текстур?*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализация создания mesh:

```
#ifndef MESH_H
#define MESH_H

#include <QString>
#include <QVector>
#include <QVector2D>
#include <QVector3D>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QOpenGLVertexArrayObject>
#include <QOpenGLExtraFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLTexture>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>

#define MAX_BONE_INFLUENCE 4

struct Vertex {
    QVector3D Position;
    QVector3D Normal;
    QVector2D TexCoords;
    QVector3D Tangent;
    QVector3D Bitangent;
    int m_BoneIDs[MAX_BONE_INFLUENCE];
    float m_Weights[MAX_BONE_INFLUENCE];
};

struct Texture {
    QOpenGLTexture texture;
    QString type;
    QString path;
    Texture() : texture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D) {
        texture.create();
        texture.setWrapMode(QOpenGLTexture::DirectionS, QOpenGLTexture::Repeat);
        texture.setWrapMode(QOpenGLTexture::DirectionT, QOpenGLTexture::Repeat);
        texture.setMinMagFilters(QOpenGLTexture::LinearMipMapLinear, QOpenGLTexture::Linear);
    }
};

class Mesh {
public:
    QVector<Vertex>       vertices;
    QVector<unsigned int> indices;
    QVector<Texture *>    textures;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram * ShaderProgram;

    Mesh(QOpenGLShaderProgram* shaderProgram);
    ~Mesh();
    void Draw();
    void setupMesh();

private:
    QOpenGLVertexArrayObject VAO;
    QOpenGLBuffer VBO,EBO;

};

#endif // MESH_H
```

---

```
#include "mesh.h"

Mesh::Mesh(QOpenGLShaderProgram* shaderProgram)
    :   ShaderProgram(shaderProgram)
    ,   VBO(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer)
    ,   EBO(QOpenGLBuffer::IndexBuffer) {
}

Mesh::~Mesh() {
    VAO.destroy();
    EBO.destroy();
    VBO.destroy();
}

void Mesh::Draw() {
    unsigned int diffuseNr = 1;
    unsigned int specularNr = 1;
    unsigned int normalNr   = 1;
    unsigned int heightNr   = 1;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < textures.size(); i++) {
        QString number;
        QString name = textures[i]->type;
        if(name == "texture_diffuse")
            number = QString::number(diffuseNr++);
        else if(name == "texture_specular")
            number = QString::number(specularNr++);
        else if(name == "texture_normal")
            number = QString::number(normalNr++);
        else if(name == "texture_height")
            number = QString::number(heightNr++);
        ShaderProgram->setUniformValue((name + number).toStdString().c_str(), i);
        textures[i]->texture.bind(i);
    }

    VAO.bind();
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}

void Mesh::setupMesh() {
    VAO.create();
    VAO.bind();

    VBO.create();
    VBO.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);

    EBO.create();
    EBO.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);

    VBO.bind();
    VBO.allocate(vertices.data(), vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex));

    EBO.bind();
    EBO.allocate(indices.data(), indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int));


    ShaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(0);
    ShaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer(0, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, sizeof(Vertex));

    ShaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(1);
    ShaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer(1, GL_FLOAT, offsetof(Vertex, Normal), 3, sizeof(Vertex));

    ShaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(2);
    ShaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer(2, GL_FLOAT, offsetof(Vertex, TexCoords), 2, sizeof(Vertex));

    ShaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(3);
    ShaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer(3, GL_FLOAT, offsetof(Vertex, Tangent), 3, sizeof(Vertex));

    ShaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(4);
    ShaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer(4, GL_FLOAT, offsetof(Vertex, Bitangent), 3, sizeof(Vertex));

    ShaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(5);
    ShaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer(5, GL_INT, offsetof(Vertex, m_BoneIDs), 4, sizeof(Vertex));

    ShaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(6);
    ShaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer(6, GL_FLOAT, offsetof(Vertex, m_Weights), 4, sizeof(Vertex));
    VAO.release();
}
```

---

```
#ifndef MODEL_H
#define MODEL_H

#include "mesh.h"
#include <QDir>

class Model {
public:
    void draw();
    void destroy();
    static Model* createModel(QString path, QOpenGLShaderProgram* shaderProgram);

private:
    Model(QString path, QOpenGLShaderProgram* shaderProgram);
    ~Model();
    QOpenGLShaderProgram * ShaderProgram;

    QVector <Texture *> Textures_loaded;
    QVector <Mesh *> Meshes;
    QDir directory;

    void processNode(aiNode *node, const aiScene *scene);
    Mesh* processMesh(aiMesh *mesh, const aiScene *scene);
    QVector<Texture*> loadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial *mat, aiTextureType type,QString typeName);
};
#endif // MODEL_H
```

---

```
#include "model.h"

#include <QOpenGLTexture>
#include <QOpenGLContext>

Model::Model(QString path, QOpenGLShaderProgram * shaderProgram)
    : ShaderProgram(shaderProgram)
    , directory(path) {

    Assimp::Importer import;
    const aiScene *scene = import.ReadFile(directory.absolutePath().toLocal8Bit(), aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs);
    if(!scene || scene->mFlags & AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode) {
        qDebug() << "ERROR::ASSIMP::"<< import.GetErrorString();
        return;
    }
    directory.cdUp();
    processNode(scene->mRootNode, scene);
}

Model::~Model () {
    for(auto &it : Textures_loaded){
        it->texture.destroy();
        delete it;
    }

    for(auto &it : Meshes){
        delete it;
    }
}

void Model::draw() {
    ShaderProgram->bind();
    for(Mesh* mesh : Meshes){
        mesh->Draw();
    }
}

void Model::destroy() {
    delete this;
}

Model *Model::createModel(QString path, QOpenGLShaderProgram *shaderProgram) {
    return new Model(path, shaderProgram);
}

void Model::processNode(aiNode *node, const aiScene *scene) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++) {
        aiMesh *mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
        Meshes.push_back(processMesh(mesh, scene));
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++) {
        processNode(node->mChildren[i], scene);
    }
}

Mesh* Model::processMesh(aiMesh *mesh,const aiScene *scene) {
    Mesh* m_mesh = new Mesh(ShaderProgram);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++) {
        Vertex vertex;
        QVector3D vector;

        vector.setX(mesh->mVertices[i].x) ;
        vector.setY(mesh->mVertices[i].y) ;
        vector.setZ(mesh->mVertices[i].z) ;
        vertex.Position = vector;

        if(mesh->mNormals) {
            vector.setX(mesh->mNormals[i].x);
            vector.setY(mesh->mNormals[i].y);
            vector.setZ(mesh->mNormals[i].z);
            vertex.Normal = vector;
        }

        if(mesh->mTextureCoords[0]) {
            QVector2D vec;
            vec.setX(mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x);
            vec.setY(mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y);
            vertex.TexCoords = vec;
        } else{
            vertex.TexCoords = QVector2D(0,0);
        }

        if(mesh->mTangents){
            vector.setX(mesh->mTangents[i].x);
            vector.setY(mesh->mTangents[i].y);
            vector.setZ(mesh->mTangents[i].z);
            vertex.Tangent = vector;
        }

        if(mesh->mBitangents){
            vector.setX(mesh->mBitangents[i].x);
            vector.setY(mesh->mBitangents[i].y);
            vector.setZ(mesh->mBitangents[i].z);
            vertex.Bitangent = vector;
        }

        m_mesh->vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++) {
        aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[i];
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++) {
            m_mesh->indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);
        }
    }

    aiMaterial* material = scene->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];

    QVector<Texture*> diffuseMaps = loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, "texture_diffuse");
    for(auto &it:diffuseMaps)
        m_mesh->textures.push_back(it);

    QVector<Texture*> specularMaps = loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_SPECULAR, "texture_specular");
    for(auto &it:specularMaps)
        m_mesh->textures.push_back(it);

    QVector<Texture*> normalMaps = loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_HEIGHT, "texture_normal");
    for(auto &it:normalMaps)
        m_mesh->textures.push_back(it);

    QVector<Texture*> heightMaps = loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_AMBIENT, "texture_height");
    for(auto &it:heightMaps)
        m_mesh->textures.push_back(it);

    m_mesh->setupMesh();
    return m_mesh;
}

QVector<Texture*> Model::loadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial *mat, aiTextureType type, QString typeName) {
    QVector<Texture*> textures;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < mat->GetTextureCount(type); i++) {
        aiString str;
        mat->GetTexture(type, i, &str);

        bool skip = false;
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < Textures_loaded.size(); j++) {
            if(std::strcmp(Textures_loaded[j]->path.toStdString().c_str(), str.C_Str()) == 0) {
                textures.push_back(Textures_loaded[j]);
                skip = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!skip) {
            Texture* texture = new Texture;
            QImage data(directory.filePath(str.C_Str()));
            if(!data.isNull()){
                texture->texture.setData(data);
                texture->type = typeName;
                texture->path = str.C_Str();
                textures.push_back(texture);
                Textures_loaded.push_back(texture);
            } else{
                qDebug () << "Не удалось успешно загружать текстуру:" << directory.filePath(str.C_Str());
            }
        }
    }
    return textures;
}
```

Comment: texture->texture.setData(data); заменил на texture->texture.setData(data.mirored());